# React Router not displaying first page in Cordova-built apk

Tags: javascript, reactjs, cordova

I have build an app with ReactJS, and it works fine in browser. My goal is to create Android/iOS app out of it now, and I've chosen Cordova for it. Some components are visible in the code below.

Everything works great in the browser - at the startup, `EventsPage` component is displayed, and `MenuBar` on the bottom as well.

However, in Android app built with Cordova, I can only see `MenuBar` at the bottom, but `EventsPage` isn't displayed. I can navigate through the app with `MenuBar` and it works as it should, but the problem is on the startup.

App.js:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import "./App.css";

import MenuBar from "./components/MenuBar";

import { BrowserRouter as Router } from "react-router-dom";

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Router>
        <MenuBar />
      </Router>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

MenuBar.js:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { css } from 'emotion';

import { BrowserRouter as Router } from 'react-router-dom';

class MenuBar extends Component {

  // some divs with menu items

        <Route path="/" exact component={EventsPage} />
        <Route path="/favorites/" component={Favorites} />
        <Route path="/party/" component={PartyPage} />
        <Route path="/about-festival/" component={AboutFestival} />
        <Route path="/details/:id" component={EventDetails} />
      </>
    );
  }
}

export default MenuBar;
```

How can I fix that? I guess that I have to do a bit more configuration for Cordova, but I can't find any useful documentation for it anywhere.

Any information is helpful, thank you!

Comment: get rid of your routes and put `EventsPage` under `App.js` and see if it works first. Just want to rule out if this is not a router issue

Comment: @windmaomao it works if I put `EventsPage` there, but of course, that component is always visible then. It's definitely issue with the Router

Answer (score 3):

I just want to say that I've found a solution  -use `HashRouter` instead of `BrowserRouter`! So, my App.js now looks like this:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';

import MenuBar from './components/MenuBar';

import { HashRouter as Router } from 'react-router-dom';

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Router>
        <MenuBar />
      </Router>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

I also added `"homepage": "./",` to my package.json file, right above the `dependencies`.

Broken Router also caused some of my images not to load, probably due to the wrong path, and that problem was also fixed with this.